# Exclude curly brace matches

Tags: regex

I have the following strings:

1. logger.debug('123', 123)
2. logger.debug(`123`,123)
3. logger.debug('1bc','test')
4. logger.debug('1bc', `test`)
5. logger.debug('1bc', test)
6. logger.debug('1bc', {})
7. logger.debug('1bc',{})
8. logger.debug('1bc',{test})
9. logger.debug('1bc',{ test })
10. logger.debug('1bc',{ test})
11. logger.debug('1bc',{test })

Instead of `debug` there can be other calls like `warn`, `fatal` etc.
All quote pairs can be `""`, `''` or ``` `` ```.

I need to create a regular express which matches case 1 - 5 but not 6 - 11.

That's what I've come up with:

```
logger.*\(['`].*['`],\s*.([^{.*}])
```

This also matches 8 - 11, so I'm suspecting this part is wrong `([^{.*}])` but I don't get it why.

Comment: Try ``logger\.\w+\(['`][^'`]*['`],\s*([^{}]*)\)`` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FdTAFv/1/))

Comment: can you arguments have values like `("123,1231", 123)` ?

Comment: You can try [`logger\.[^(]+\([^,]+,[^{}]+?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/xUZ25W/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac yes that's indeed possible as well as `('123,1231', "123")` or even `("123,1231", `123`)`

Comment: If you want matching quotes, perhaps ``logger\.[^(\r\n]+\((?:(['`"])[^'`"]+\1|\w+),[^{}\r\n]+[`']*\)`` https://regex101.com/r/tO4QAK/1

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler also do you have non string values as arguments ? and can you arguments have escaped string i.e `'vivek\'s name` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird this seems to work

Comment: @CodeManiac no there are no escaped strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
logger\.[^(]+\((?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|'(?:\\'|[^'])*'|`(?:\\`|[^`])*`),[^{}]*?\)
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/xUZ25W/3/)

P.S:- This pattern can be shorten if we are sure there won't be any mismatch of quotes, also if there won't be any escaped quote inside string

If there's no escaped string

```
logger\.[^(]+\((?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|`[^`]*`),[^{}]*?\)
```

If there's no quotes in between string. i.e no strings like `"mr's jhon`

```
logger\.[^(]+\(([`"'])[^"'`]*\1,[^{}]*?\)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no quotes between the quoted parts, you could make use of a capturing group to match one of the quote types `` (['`"]) `` and use a backreference `\1` to match the closing quote type.

The `\r\n` in the negated character class is to not cross newline boundaries.

The pattern will match either the quoted parts or 1+ times a word character for the first part.

The second part matches any char except `{` or `}` or `)` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
logger\.[^(\r\n]+\((?:(['`"])[^'`"]+\1|\w+),[^{})\r\n]+\)
```

That will match

- `logger\.` Match `logger.`
- `[^(\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `(` or a newline
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `` (['`"]) `` Capture **group 1**
  - `` [^'`"]+\1 `` Match 1+ times any char except the quote types, backreference to the captured
  - `|` or
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `),` Close non capture group and match `,`
- `[^{})\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `{` `}` `)` or a newline
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQTEq0/1)